# unix home space does not appear in wine

Tags: wine

I am running Wine on Ubuntu 22.04.

If I open the Windows Explorer (or any other application) on Wine and try to open a file, I can see that `z:` is mapped (as expected) to `/`. Navigating to `z:\home` works too, but although another user directory appears there, my own home space does not. Likewise, directly using the full path of my home spaces fails.

It's very strange. I have checked permissions on my own home space, which seem correct, and anyway, I am running wine as myself including executing files in my home space. These applications cannot see the home space.

I have no idea what could be happening. It does work on other installations.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually find the answer here, by adding the application to winecfg and moving the profile to Windows XP. The full home space now appears.

Comment: Great you found your solution :-) The answer would be better if you [edited](https://superuser.com/posts/1776847/edit) it and added the exact steps you took to resolve the issue. That way another person who might not be as well-versed with Wine - take me for example - would be able to resolve the issue with your answer.